# I can compile the same c++ code on different linux?

Tags: c++, compilation, centos, debian

I have a question about c ++, I am developing a server code in c ++ for linux systems, but a question arises, I am developing on a debian system since for convenience it is the one I like the most to work with, but a Once it is launched into production, it will be done in a centos, so the following question arises.

Can I compile the same c ++ code with g ++ on both a debian and centos (redhat) system, or can I find incompatibilities?
Could you even compile the code to debian and just pass the binaries to production or is it not good practice?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't use debian specific code it will compile just fine on centos.